# Problems trying to post a second answer to question (second from same user)

Tags: support, bug

So I was trying to update [this question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/examples-of-good-homework-questions) with a link to another well asked question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/178722/determining-straining-force-and-reaction-forces-on-a-beam#comment379180_178722) - I tried twice, but each time my answer did not appear- I am wondering if it is being checked because I asked the original question and already posted one answer...

...the idea was to post [good examples of homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/examples-of-good-homework-questions) as separate answers, which is why I want to add a second answer.

Any idea what is going on? I typed out an answer twice and both hit post both times, but nothing seemed to appear....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably caused by a [SE script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202805) that automatically converts short answers into [comments](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/examples-of-good-homework-questions#comment25159_6442).

Comment: thanks @Qmechanic - that makes sense and now I can see them and I feel stupid for asking the question - best wishes, Tom