# Examples of the questioner going the extra mile

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm trying to improve my penning-down-a-question skills. I have been through [the guidelines](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and this great [meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). I was hoping to get some examples (/list) of a well phrased question. In order to help my own question framing.

Would any user like to provide such examples (/list)? More specifically, examples (/list) which clearly shows the questioner posting on a nuanced topic and going the extra mile so that the audience has clarity what he/she is going about.

I'm sure there are questions that everyone can agree are well put. And there is visible effort that the questioner has gone the extra mile.

Comment: I think what would be helpful here is to say why the examples in the help center/meta are not sufficient for you. In my opinion those references should have great examples. So if you are looking for something beyond these sources you should go into that here.

Comment: @AaronStevens in the links I've provided "the guidelines" and "great meta post" they are both don't cite a question which has been well written. They merely provide "guidelines" and "tips". The reason I ask for examples (/list) is I find it quite easy to follow when these "guidelines" and "tips" are exemplified by a question post where the poster is an adherent.

Comment: I meant this lists in the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I'm sure there are more around there.

Comment: @AaronStevens Didn't know about that link. I find it awful to navigate through this site and often just use google. That link didn't show up. My bad.

Comment: The [FAQ](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11305/faq-for-physics-stack-exchange?r=SearchResults) could be somewhat helpful too, although probably not what you are looking for exactly.

Comment: I'd suggest perusing highly voted questions. While being highly upvoted may not be directly caused by it being well phrased, the opposite (downvoted and poorly phrased) seems well correlated (yes causation and correlation are not the same - still).

Comment: possible duplicates: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9839/84967, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10938/84967, https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6442/84967